# Such that "|" and ":", what's the difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have encountered a statement like this:

$z=\{x \in X | \forall y \in Y : d_{xy} = NULL\}$

It's supposedly getting as set of $z$ out of table $d$ where in column $x$, row $y$ is empty. But the symbol $|$ used, isn't it supposed to be $\land$? Or "such that" is a legitimate way of expression in this case? Then what's the difference between $|$ and $:$, aren't they both "such that"?

Comment: The ":" here is just separating two statements.  I would have used a comma.  This is "the set of all members, x, of X such that, for all members, y, of Y, dxy= NULL".

Comment: No difference. See [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate).

Comment: To write $\{ x \in A \mid \varphi (x) \}$ is a different way to write $\{ x \mid x \in A \land \varphi(x) \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $:$ **often** means "such that" in general. You can encounter it anywhere outside of set builder notation. But in the specific case of set builder notation; i.e. when you have
$$S=\{x:p(x)\}$$
it is also accepted convention to instead write
$$ S = \{x\mid p(x)\}.$$
You won't, however, see something like $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\mid\dots$ anytime soon. $\mid$ and $:$ are interchangeable within set builder notation, and everywhere else, the convention of using $:$ is adopted.

Do note, however, that $:$ can be used in a more versatile way than this. We often see things like $\{ x^2:x\in\mathbb Z\}$, which English grammar wouldn't permit a reading like "$x^2$ such that $x$ is in $\mathbb Z$". Instead, a better way of thinking about this would be "$x^2$ for each $x$ in $\mathbb Z$". Also, we can have functions denoted $f:A\to B$ which should be interpreted as "$f$ is a function mapping $A$ into $B$"; and you'll often see $f:x\mapsto y$, which can be interpreted as "$f$ is a function that takes the element $x$ to the element $y$". In each of these cases, it wouldn't make grammatical sense to force the term "such that", but I suppose you can if you want to. In general then, $:$ meaning "such that" is a good rule of thumb, but you should definitely consider the context when deciding the meaning.

Comment: Just saying, the meaning 'such that' works just fine for $f: A\to B$. Note that $A\to B$ should be read as _'a function that maps $A$ to $B$'_. So we have $f$ such that it's a function that maps $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @IlikeSerena: If you're willing to twist $f : A \to B$ to mean 'we have $f$ such that it's a function that maps $A$ to $B$', then you could argue that any symbol at all means 'such that'. For example $3 \times 5$ is 'the number such that when you multiply $3$ by $5$ you get it', and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ means 'we have $n$ such that it's a natural number'. The point is that $:$ doesn't mean 'such that' in general, and shouldn't be read that way except in certain circumstances. YiFan updated their answer accordingly. (+1, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

I have always thought $\mid$ and $:$ were interchangeable;   and have used them that way.

As in the comments,  here $:$ appears to serve a different purpose.